# When my app is not running (only when not running), why does my BroadcastReceiver give me a nullpointer exception?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I will try to sum up simply because my original code is long. Suppose that My broadcast receiver is like this :

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static ArrayList<String> phonenumber_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> message_array = new ArrayList<String>();

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {

        sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

           phonenumber_array.add(0,sms[i].getOriginatingAddress());
           message_array.add(0,sms[i].getMessageBody());

           com.test.ListActivityClass.myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, The BroadcastReceiver has the IntentFilter "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED".

My ListActivityClass extends ListActivity, contains a myadapter which is an ArrayAdapter, like : myadapter = new CustomAdapter (this,com.test.SMSBroadcastReceiver.phonenumber_array,com.test.SMSBroadcastReceiver.message_array)

So my problem is : I send an sms from eclipse to emulator. whenever myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is called in my BroadcastReceiver when my application is not running(completely stoped, no process launched, no activities) , I get a nullpointer exception.

When I remove myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the problem is gone.

When the app is running, there is no problem as well, my application gets correctly the new sms received and displays it in the list.

So my guess was = When the app is running, the BroadcastReceiver can detect the myadapter, because the app is in memory, so it can notify changes. when the app isn't running, it is not in memory so BroadcastReceiver can't see any myadapter, so it gives a nullpointer exception. it makes sense.
So I tried to check : if the process is in memory, notify changes, else, don't notify ( because my applications gets all the sms received onCreate(), so it is not necessary.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcInfo = activityManager
    .getRunningAppProcesses(); for (int i1 = 0; i1 <
    runningProcInfo.size(); i1++) { 

    if (runningProcInfo.get(i1).processName.equals("com.test")) {
            com.test.ListActivityClass.myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But nothing changed. I still have a nullpointer exception when app is not running.

The worst thing is, I tried to replace phonenumber_array by phonenumber_array.add(0,"somephonenumber"); and message_array.add(0,"somemessage"); to check if a BroadcastReceiver runs in the backround even if the app is closed, my thoughts were correct. After the null pointer exception, I launched the app, and somephonenumber and somemessage were both present.

What do I miss? Does a BroadcastReceiver runs in background, or only when application launches? what is wrong?

Comment: Your app will be started when the BroadcastReceiver is received if it is not already running. Has to be who else would be running the code, the OS thread? Nope as that would be a security hole. Is 'myadapter' an object, if so how is it allocated? From reading your post of cause it will be null.

Comment: Move static state like this `myadapter` thingie to the Application object - you will have a more explicit lifecycle for things for easier debugging of such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, static data members (and the comment-suggested replacement, `Application`) only live as long as your process lives. Your process may go away microseconds after `onReceive()` completes.

If you want to use static data members as a cache, that's fine, but durable data needs to live on the filesystem (database, flat file, etc.).

Second, `myadapter` should not be a static data member. You are leaking memory.

Either:

- Move this `BroadcastReceiver` to be registered by the activity via `registerReceiver()`, or
- Have this `BroadcastReceiver` send another ordered broadcast to be picked up by the running activity (if it is in the foreground), as is described in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) and is demonstrated in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid)

Comment: The fact is, before stocking all sms in arrays, I was using a CursorAdapter, which was working fantastic, because everything was immediate on application start, even with tons of messages, and didn't have to deal with notify adapter. But What I don't manage to get with cursor adapter is to regroup all sms came from a sender into one item in the list, which is apparently impossible with a cursor adapter from the answer I received on another post.

Comment: So I have to regroup all in arrays, but the application's gui starts seconds after it has loaded all messages ( I think it is due to while (cursor.movetonext()) for requesting messages, because there is no choice). The simpliest and best way would be to be able to merge all sms from a sender into one item in my ListView but how to do it? is it possible to like , skip inflating if the sender's number is already seen, or whatever? There must be a simple solution, the default messaging app does it very quick. How?

Comment: I already tried asynctask but the result is the same, the gui is loaded, but messages get seconds to load, which is the same..

Answer (score 0):

You can create static boolean variable `onScreen` and set it to `true` in `onResume` method, and set to `false` in `onPause` method. It is the easiest way to understand if application is on the screen

Comment: I already did it before, but anyway, the problem doesn't occur onPause. It is only when there is no process of the app running ( like if the app was forced to close, anyway I have seen this bug when I did this, otherwise I would not.